# Flutter - How to fetch data from website that has Cloudflare DDOS protection

Tags: http, flutter, dart, cloudflare

I'm trying to fetch data from my website. But when I print `response.body` I get the body of Cloudflare DDOS protection design's body. Here is my code:

```
  var url = 'https://example.com/mycontroller/myfunction/' + myParameter;
  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  print(url.toString());
  print(response.body.toString());
```

Here is he output:

```
I/flutter ( 5748): <!DOCTYPE HTML>
I/flutter ( 5748): <html lang="en-US">
I/flutter ( 5748): <head>
I/flutter ( 5748):   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
I/flutter ( 5748):   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
I/flutter ( 5748):   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
I/flutter ( 5748):   <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
I/flutter ( 5748):   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
I/flutter ( 5748):   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="12">
I/flutter ( 5748):   <title>Just a moment...</title>
I/flutter ( 5748):   <style type="text/css">
I/flutter ( 5748):     html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
I/flutter ( 5748):     body {background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000; font-family:-apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, "Helvetica Neue",Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.7em;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}
I/flutter ( 5748):     h1 { text-align: center; font-weight:700; margin: 16px 0; font-size: 32px; color:#000000; line-height: 1.25;}
I/flutter ( 5748):     p {font-size: 20px; font-weight: 400; margin: 8px 0;}
I/flutter ( 5748):     p, .attribution, {text-align: center;}
I/flutter ( 5748):     #spinner {margin: 0 auto
```

I try to check status code and I get the 503 status code. How can I pass the DDOS protection and get my data?